# Get all max values based on two fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, max

I'd like to know if there a way to fetch from a MongoDB database, the max value based on an attribute (for example : versioning),

In my case, I've two documents

```
   [{_id:"fjezfjojef", book:"Don't Kill The Mockinbird", version:1},
   {_id:"fjezfjojeg", book:"Don't Kill The Mockinbird", version:2}]
```

I'd like to get from Mongo, only the last version, what's the neatest way to solve this problem?

I'm using Mongo 3.2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I wanted to show you the difference between a find query and the aggregation.

Suppose we have the following documents:

> db.books.find({}, {_id: 0})

```
{ "book" : "To Kill a Mockingbird", "version" : 1 }
{ "book" : "To Kill a Mockingbird", "version" : 2 }
{ "book" : "To Kill a Mockingbird", "version" : 3 }
{ "book" : "MongoDB Learning", "version" : 1 }
{ "book" : "MongoDB Learning", "version" : 2 }
{ "book" : "MongoDB Learning", "version" : 3 }
{ "book" : "Test Book", "version" : 1 }
{ "book" : "Test Book", "version" : 2 }
```

If you run the find query - you will only return the matched book:

> db.books.find({book:"To Kill a Mockingbird"}, {_id: 0}).sort({version:-1}).limit(1)

```
{ "book" : "To Kill a Mockingbird", "version" : 3 }
```

If you run an aggregation query - you will get all of the books, and THEN return the max version for each.

> db.books.aggregate([
>   ...     { $group: { _id: "$book", "version": { "$max": "$version" } } }
>   ... ])

```
{ "_id" : "Test Book", "version" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "MongoDB Learning", "version" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "To Kill a Mockingbird", "version" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This will group by the book title - and return the document with the max version for each book.

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$book", "version": { "$max": "$version" } } }
])
```

Comment: I just solved my issue with this : `db.books.find({'book':"Don't Kill The Mockinbird"}).sort({version:-1}).limit(1)`

Comment: That will only find you that one book, if you have multiple kinds of books, you won't find them.

Comment: What do you mean by that? If the books are identified by their title in the query, MongoDB should retrieve them.

Comment: Ok... so the find query will match all books that are "Don't Kill the Mockinbird" --> Then sort them by version, and return the first one.

The aggregate query will find EVERY book, and get the latest version for each book.  

I'll revise my answer to show you the difference.

Comment: See the other answer, let me know if you have any questions.  It seemed like you were trying to find all books and not just the one book so I wanted to give you a more dynamic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.books.find({'book':"Don't Kill The Mockinbird"}).sort({version:-1}).limit(1)
```